# Should images be resized to their final size?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I use a bunch of images and icons in my app frequently in different sizes. Let's say a help icon is used sometimes in a 32x32 image view, sometimes its shown in an image view of size 120x120.

At the moment I have saved the image file at size 512x512px. However, I wonder whether it makes sense to save the image at both resolutions, e.g. create a 32x32 and 120x120 version, or only a 120x120 version.

Do too big images have impact on performance or will aliasing problems occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resize them because of the following reasons:

- if you have many small images on a screen, it will need less memory
- using scaled down big pictures in a tableview makes it noticeable not smooth scrolling
- the shown pictures will have the best quality if they are rendered 1:1